# mistake comparing datetime, python

Tags: python, datetime

i wrote this code

```
import time
import datetime
import os
import msvcrt as m

while True:
    try:
        os.system("cls")

        delivery = input("Insert delivery date (dd/mm/aaaa): ")
        dateDelivery = datetime.datetime.strptime(delivery,     "%d%m%Y").strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        dateInput = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

    except ValueError:
        print("\nWrong format\n\nTry again")
        m.getch()
        continue 

    if dateDelivery <= dateInput:

        print("\nThe inserted date has already past\n\n", dateDelivery, "\n\nla Actual date: ", dateInput)
        m.getch()
        continue 

    else:
        break               

print("Input date: ", dateInput, "\nDelivery date: ", dateDelivery)
```

It needs to compare 2 dates: a date to send a delivery and the actual date, so if te date to send the delivery is a past date, the program send a message indicating that.

The program works fine, but if i insert some dates in future, the program recognize them as a past dates. Try with 12122016.

I'm very newbie at code, so i think this is a very simple mistake.

Sorry about my english, i'm trying to improve it here too

thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're comparing between two dates converted to **string** type, so the comparation is lexicographic. You should use **datetime** type like this:

```
    dateDelivery = datetime.datetime.strptime(delivery,"%d%m%Y")
    dateInput = datetime.datetime.now()
```

You can see the difference by printing the type of the variables:

```
    print(type(dateDelivery))
    print(type(dateInput))
```

before and after the change.

Comment: Thank you!! :D This solve my problem. I'm not actually able to undestand it at all, but it gives me some direction to keep my studyes.
I din't use 'datetime.now' because it gives me extra data about time, i just need day, month and Year. But the problem no longer exist.

Thanks again

Comment: @MisterPresident you're welcome. Try understand the concept of types and always be aware to the type of the objects you're working with. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you obtain a datetime value, you covert it to a string using `strftime("%d/%m/%Y")`. So when you compare `dateDelivery` with `dateInput`, you are comparing two pieces of text, not datetime values.

When using a `dd-mm-yyyy` format, the ordering of text does not always correspond to datetime ordering (if you really wanted to, you could use a `yyyy-mm-dd` format, which has correct ordering).

For example:

```
>>> "01/01/2015" <= "01/01/2016"
True
>>> "02/01/2015" <= "01/01/2016" # wrong?
False
```

So when asking before comparing the dates, you should not convert them to strings.

```
dateDelivery = datetime.datetime.strptime(delivery, "%d%m%Y")
dateInput = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Then, when showing the results to the user, you can convert them to strings:

```
humanDateInput = dateInput.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
humanDateDelivery = dateDelivery.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
print("Input date:", humanDateInput)
print("Delivery date:", humanDateDelivery)
```

Comment: I really appreciate your explanation, it helps me to understand my mistakes.

Thank you